# Image of function injected into vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory

Let $f:A \to W$. with $A$ some open set of a vector space $V$ and $W$ a vector space. $f$ is always *onto* its image $f(A)$ and there is the decomposition
$$
f:A \xrightarrow{ \ f_{sur} \ }f(A) \xrightarrow{ \ f_{injective}  \ }W.
$$

I would like to know if it is always possible to inject $f(A)$ into a vector space $W$ like above. If so, is $W$ the vector space generated by $f(A)$? Or is $W$ the "free vector space over the set $f(A)$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, given any subset of a vector space, there is always a least vector space containing it, called the linear span, linear hull, or just the space generated by $f(A)$. Then $f(A)$ will inject into its linear span.

> If so, is $W$ the vector space generated by $f(A)$?

If $W$ is finite dimensional, then only if $f(A)$ has the same dimension as $W$. Otherwise no. And in fact if $W$ is infinite dimensional, it will be possible for $f(A)$ to have the same dimension as $W$ and still not generate all of $W$.

> Or is $W$ the "free vector space over the set $f(A)$"?

No, the free vector space construction on a set produces a new vector space with as many basis vectors as in your set. For example the free vector space on a 1-dimensional real vector space produces a $c$-dimensional vector space, where $c$ is the cardinality of the continuum (the real line). $W$ is not the free vector space generated by $f(A)$

Comment: Agreed, but, $f:A \to W$ cannot be linear, as $A$ is an open set, not a subspace of $V$, right?

Comment: @EEEB oh, I assumed $f$ _was_ linear. If that is not intended then I shall revise my answer.

Comment: @EEEB how about now?

Comment: better, thanks! Is the linear span not the same as the vector space generated by f(A)?

Comment: @EEEB they are the same thing. In case this is mostly a terminological question, I edited my answer to make clear that "linear span" and "set generated by" are the same thing.

Comment: Also one other question what is c, in your answer about the free vector space generated? Is it the cardinality of the set?

Comment: @EEEB yes, c is the cardinality of the real line. It's a very large cardinality (exactly how large is undecidable in ZFC), so the point was to show how badly the proposal "free vector space on a subset gives the whole space" can fail. Here the free vector space on a 1-dimensional space gives an uncountably infinite dimensional space. If you consider vector spaces over finite fields, the failure will not be as bad.